# Why this XSL template renders / generate 2 times?

Tags: xml, xslt

I started my first adventure with xsl today in hope of doing this "easy" script quickly.
Now 4 h later I still dont know why it generate 2 times...

I need your help with finding a error in my script, because I can't find it myself...

I'm creating HTML form based on XML with XSL.
I basically have one template that is automaticly created two times. And I only want the one in `<div class="columnDiv">`.

**Screenshot with** [error reasult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHtWA.jpg).
**Screenshots with what I want to** [achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKB55.jpg).

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<labels>
    <options>
        <option type="Top Text 1"/>
        <option type="Top Text 2"/>
        <option type="Top Text 2"/>
    </options>
    <statuses>
        <status type="Correct">
            <answer description="Yes"/>
            <answer description="No"/>
        </status>
        <status type="Error - Type 1">
            <answer description="Option 1"/>
            <answer description="Option 2"/>
            <answer description="Option 3"/>
            <answer description="Option 4"/>
        </status>
        <status type="Error - Type 2">
            <answer description="Option 1"/>
            <answer description="Option 2"/>
            <answer description="Option 3"/>
            <answer description="Option 4"/>
        </status>
    </statuses>
</labels>
```

**My XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <form method="POST" action="new-process.php">
            <div class="mainC">
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="options">
        <xsl:for-each select="option"> 

            <div class="columnDiv">
                <h3><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></h3>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/statuses"/>
            </div>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="status">
        <xsl:for-each select="."> 
                <label><xsl:value-of select ="@type"/></label>
                <select>
                    <xsl:for-each select="answer"> 
                            <option><xsl:value-of select="@description"/></option>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </select>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Current Output with Comments on Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form method="POST" action="new-process.php">
    <div class="mainC">
        <div class="columnDiv">
            <h3>Top Text 1</h3>
            <label>Correct</label><select><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select>
            <label>Error - Type 1</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
            <label>Error - Type 2</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
        </div>
        <div class="columnDiv">
            <h3>Top Text 2</h3>
            <label>Correct</label><select><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select>
            <label>Error - Type 1</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
            <label>Error - Type 2</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
        </div>
        <div class="columnDiv">
            <h3>Top Text 2</h3>
            <label>Correct</label><select><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select>
            <label>Error - Type 1</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
            <label>Error - Type 2</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
        </div>

        <!-- \ this is the output that I do no want \ -->
        <label>Correct</label><select><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select>
        <label>Error - Type 1</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
        <label>Error - Type 2</label><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option></select>
        <!-- / this is the output that I do no want / -->

    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: XSLT Fiddle of Question: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BX

Comment: Your first Apply-Templates has no filter; so applies more templates than just the options.  Add `select="/labels/options"` to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments, to get the solution you're after you only need to add `select="/labels/options"` to your first apply-templates statement.  @TimC gives a great explanation of this in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046009/361842).

That said, you've also used a lot of `for-each` loops in your code.  Generally with XSL it's better to use templates in such scenarios as it makes for cleaner code*.  Here's a tweaked version with those loops removed:  http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BX/3

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <form method="POST" action="new-process.php">
            <div class="mainC">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/options"/> 
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="options/option">
        <div class="columnDiv">
            <h3><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></h3>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/statuses"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="status">
            <label><xsl:value-of select ="@type"/></label>
            <select>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./answer"/>
            </select>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="answer">
            <option><xsl:value-of select="@description"/></option>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*I'd originally stated that this also improved parallel processing; but as Martin points out in the comments some engines support parallel processing for `for-each` too; and I couldn't find any documentation to support my original statement; so suspect it's apocryphal.

Comment: While I completely agree with the reasoning that using template matching and apply-templates makes for cleaner code I would like to know which XSLT processor in your experience "matches in parallel" but executes `for-each` sequentially as loop. Saxon certainly supports parallel processing for `for-each`: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/for-each.html (only the commercial flagship EE has such advanced features anyway but I don't  think the open-source version offers parallel processing for template matching). That shows that the spec doesn't restrict `for-each` to a loop.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen; it's something I'd read when first learning; but seems to not be the case universally, so I'll remove from my answer.  Having a quick scan I can find this rule implied (e.g. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiploop/, https://www.quora.com/XSLT-When-should-the-xsl-for-each-be-used), but no hard evidence / official documentation to support.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made a bad start at all, but you now need to learn about XSLT's [Built in Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule). These are templates that will be used when there is no matching template in your XSLT.

You have a template matching the document node `/`, in which you do `<xsl:apply-templates />`. This will select the `label` node, for which you have no template. So the default template is this...

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

And this will select the `options` and `statuses` nodes. You have a template matching `options` so that is good, but not one matching `statuses`, so the built-in one kicks in again.

But in your `options` template you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/statuses"/>` which ultimately results in the `statuses` (and the child `status` nodes) getting selected twice.

One solution is to change the `<xsl:apply-templates />` in the `/` node to explicitly only select `options` only, like so...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <form method="POST" action="new-process.php">
        <div class="mainC">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="labels/options"/> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</xsl:template>
```